# Laravel Excel- ¿como no tomar encuenta hojas vacías al importar?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

El problema principal es que al importar un archivo excel con 3 hojas, si una o 2 estan vacias , obtengo el siguiente error:

> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception
> Start row (2) is beyond highest row (1)

lo que tiene sentido ya que solo detecta el encabezado.

este es parte de mi archivo de importación principal:

```
....
....
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;//
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;//
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnError;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsErrors;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RemembersRowNumber;//
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMappedCells;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithConditionalSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows; 

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;


class UploadInventarioPrediosSVD implements ,
WithHeadingRow,WithValidation,SkipsOnFailure
,OnEachRow,WithMultipleSheets,SkipsEmptyRows
{

 public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
             'InventarioGeneral' => new PredioInventarioGeneralSVD(),
             'IngresosGeneral' => new PredioIngresoSVD(),
             'SalidasGeneral'=> new PredioDespachoSVD(),
        ];
    }
}
```

alguna forma que conoscan?
intente de esta forma :

```
 if (empty($row['name'])|| is_null($row['name'])){
            return;
}
```

Comment: Prueba pasando a `true` la clave [ignore_empty](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/a0bdbded2c530e696bc4dadbe7fbd5051915f8bb/config/excel.php#L100) del archivo de configuración

Comment: O [validando las filas](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html)